# Why is my table's edges not square when they should be?

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have a big table, I'm going to try to make a game. I need all the table parts to be square, but the edges are more rectangular. I can't find anything to help fix this.

I've tried setting the max width and height of `tr` and `th` to 6.667vw(approx. 1/15 of the screen width) but the edge sizes are still too big to be the small round error. I've erased the width and height of `tr` and `th` to see if it was something of that, but that didn't work either. I have a lot of table elements, a 15x15, I am giving the smallest amount possible for my given problem; I am also adding the css.

## Css:

```
* {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

table {

  width: 100%;

  height: 100vw;

  border: 3px solid red;

  border-collapse: collapse;

}

tr th {

  border: 2px solid black;

}
```

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Scrabble</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="game">

      <div class="board">

        <table>

          <tr class="row1">

            // 15 <tr> elements with

            // incrementing 'col#' classes

          </tr>

          <tr class="row2"> // class 'row#' incremented by 1

            // 15 <tr> elements

          </tr>

          // 13 more <tr> elements with

          // incrementing 'row#' classes

        </table>

      </div>

      <div class="letterSelect"></div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Sorry for the html with no  elements, I wanted to keep it concise while giving you enough detail to replicate. The class names have no functionality, but I included them because they are in my code. I hope this is enough.

Comment: This code isn't runnable. Provide some more info so we can answer (:

Comment: You have `// 15 <tr> elements with... // incrementing 'col#' classes` within your `<tr>` elements? Did you mean `<td>`? And why aren't those elements in your code, so that it can show what you're really doing, and working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is you shouldn't really use a `<table>` to make your game board. A `<table>` should be used for displaying tabular data. [More information about tables on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

I would advise using `display:grid` to make your board instead. [More information about grid layout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

I have created [a codepen to use as a starting point](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/eYKbwWy?editors=1100). The code is also shown below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="game">
    <div class="board">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <!-- 224 more .square elements to make your 15 x 15 board -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.game {
    padding: 20px; // just to add some breathing space to the demo
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 5vmin); // substitute 5vmin for whatever size you like, just make sure to use the same value for grid-template-rows
    grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 5vmin);
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.square {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, will work. But i have a request; is it possible to make the outside border collapse like a table? If not it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Sort of. Do you want to do that so you can have the 3px red border round the outside of the board and 2px wide dividing lines between the squares?

Comment: no, I think. I want there to be no gap between the outside squares and the outer border. kind of like ```border-collapse: collapse;``` with a table.

Comment: The solution above does not have a gap between the outside squares and the outer border. I have created a second codepen with the code above. I edited the original to have a 3px red border round the board whilst keeping the 2px borders between the squares. Hopefully that will help by giving you a couple of alternatives to achieving your goal.

Comment: it's fine. There is a gap for me but it is no big deal. it is a small one(1 or 2 px). thank you for your solution and have a good day! cheers!

Comment: not entirely sure why you're seeing a gap. try setting box-sizing on *, *::before and *::after to border-box